# Get node from php array by one of the fields

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with structure generated like this:

```
$groups = array();
while ($group = mysql_fetch_array($groups_result)) {
        $groups[] = array( 'id' => $group['id'], 'name' => $group['name']);
    }
```

How can I later in the code get the name of the group by its id? For example, I would like a function like:

```
function get_name_by_id($id, $array);
```

But I'm looking for some solution which is already implemented in PHP. I know it would be easier to make arrays with array[5] = array('name' => "foo") etc where 5 in this case is id, but in my code there is a lot of arrays already created like i mentioned above and I cannot easily switch it.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. What problem do you have in implementing a function like `get_name_by_id($id)`?

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

Comment: pass the array also into ur function

Comment: I don't have a problem with implementing such function, I just wanted to know if there is a function implemented already in PHP which would get me the contents by the node?

Comment: @KeluThatsall there is no built-in function for that

Comment: So I cannot search for like an "id" field with some value and get key of the array which contains the "id" field with the exact value i provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$groups = array();
while ($group = mysql_fetch_assoc($groups_result)) {
    $groups[$group['id']] = array( 'name' => $group['name']);
}

$name = $groups['beer']['name'];
```

also please not using fetch_assoc is more efficient than fetch array

Comment: I know I can do that, but I have a lot of instances of arrays which are already created with this way and I don't want to switch the idea now

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_name_by_id($id, $data) {
    foreach($data as $d) {
        if ($d['id'] == $id) {
            return $d['name'];
        }
    }
    // return something else, id was not found
}
```

Comment: I'm not looking for exact solution, I could write a function like that. I was looking for a solution already implemented in PHP, is there some function which would work like that.